# Flutter How to convert List <string>to List<custom type>? Event type

Tags: android, flutter, events, calendar

I try to persist an Event data type in my project

```
loadEventList() async {
  await _init();
  final _ev = _prefs.getStringList('eventList');
  List<Event> listToEvent = _ev as List<Event>;
  return _events = listToEvent;
}
```

I've got this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Event>' in type cast
```

Can somebody help me find a way to convert my list into an event list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using the map function would help

```
_events = _ev.map((String element){return  Event(param);});
```